# Rank of a matrix with real entries

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $5 \times 4$ matrix with real entries such that space of all solutions of the linear system $AX^t=[1,2,3,4,5]^t$ is given by $\{[1+2s,2+3s,3+4s,4+5s]^t : s \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

(here $M^t$ denotes the transpose of a matrix $M$).

Then the rank of $A$ is

**a)** $4$

**b)** $3$

**c)** $2$

**d)** $1$

---

**Here is what I've tried:**

In this question, dim(Axt) will be $2$. Hence, by the rank-nullity theorem, $\operatorname*{rank} A=4-2=2$. I do not know the answer of this question.

Comment: Show what you have tried, where you got stuck etc.

Comment: Dim(AX^t)= [1,2,3,4,]+s[2,3,4,5]

Comment: I am not gettng what to do next...

Comment: It is 5*4 matrix.. I checked it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C:=\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3\\4\\5\end{pmatrix}$, $K_1:=\begin{pmatrix}2\\3\\4\\5\end{pmatrix}$ and $L:=\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3\\4\end{pmatrix}.$

Initial equation yields

$$\tag{1} \forall s, \ \ \ A(L+sK_1)=C.$$

Taking in (1), two different values of $s$ and subtracting gives : $AK_1=0$, which means that $K_1 \in Ker(A)$. Thus, as $K_1 \neq 0, dim(Ker(A)) \geq 1$ ; thus $dim(range(A))=rank(A) \leq 3$ (by rank nullity theorem).

Let us assume that $rank(A)<3$ and show that it leads to a contradiction.

It would mean that dim $Ker(A) \geq 2$ for the same reason as above.

Thus, there would exist a second vector $K_2$ in the kernel of $A$, independent from $K_1$. By definition: $$\tag{2}AK_2=0.$$

Combining (1) and (2), we would have:

$$\forall s, \forall t, \ \ \ A(L+sK_1+tK_2)=C.$$

In this way, the general solution to equation $AX=C$ would no longer be $X=L+sK_1$, but a larger set (2D or 3D affine subspace instead of an affine line). Contradiction with the above assumption.

Thus $rank(A)=3 \ $ (answer b)).